# Add a column with sequence values if conditions of value in another column with binary values is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe df with column A with random numbers and column B with categories. Now, I obtain another column C using the code below:

```
df.loc[df['A'] >= 50, 'C'] = 1 
df.loc[df['A'] < 50, 'C'] = 0
```

I want to obtain a column 'D' which creates a sequence if 1 is encountered else returns the value 0. The required dataframe is given below.

**Required df**

```
A   B   C   D
17  a   0   0
88  a   1   1
99  a   1   2
76  a   1   3
73  a   1   4
23  b   0   0
36  b   0   0
47  b   0   0
74  b   1   1
80  c   1   1
77  c   1   2
97  d   1   1
30  d   0   0
80  d   1   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['D'] = df.groupby(['B', 'C']).cumcount().add(1).mask(df['C'].eq(0), 0)
print (df)
A   B   C   D
17  a   0   0
88  a   1   1
99  a   1   2
76  a   1   3
73  a   1   4
23  b   0   0
36  b   0   0
47  b   0   0
74  b   1   1
80  c   1   1
77  c   1   2
97  d   1   1
30  d   0   0
80  d   1   2
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['D'] = np.where(df['C'].eq(0), 0, df.groupby(['B', 'C']).cumcount().add(1))
```